# Circular reveal transition for new activity

Tags: android, animation, material-design

As per https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

> The `ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal()` method enables you to
>   animate a clipping circle to reveal or hide a view.
>
> To reveal a previously invisible view using this effect:
>
> ```
> // previously invisible view
> View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
>
> // get the center for the clipping circle
> int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2;
> int cy = (myView.getTop() + myView.getBottom()) / 2;
>
> // get the final radius for the clipping circle
> int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());
>
> // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
> Animator anim =
>     ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
>
> // make the view visible and start the animation
> myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
> anim.start();
> ```

This is meant to reveal a view. How can I use this to circularly reveal an entire activity, without any shared elements?

Specifically, I'd like my searchActivity to circularly reveal from the search action button in the toolbar.

Comment: Nope. Not actively looking for it anymore.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

After looking for a solution for half a day without a result, I came up with an own implementation. I'm using a transparent activity with a matching root layout.
The root layout is a view which can then be revealed with `createCircularReveal()`.

My code looks like this:

**Theme Definition in styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**Activity Definition in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.CircularRevealActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        />
```

then I declared a layout for my activity (I've chosen DrawerLayout, so that I can have a NavDrawer. Every layout should work here.)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/honey_melon"
        >

        <!-- Insert your actual layout here -->

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Important is the FrameLayout with the id `root_layout`. This view will be revealed in the activity.

Finally I implemented `CircularRevealActivity` and overwrote `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.do_not_move, R.anim.do_not_move);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reveal_circular);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        rootLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    circularRevealActivity();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } 
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It was important to put `circularRevealActivity()` into a `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, because the view needs to be drawn for the animation.

`circularRevealActivity()` looks like Ishaan's proposal:

```
private void circularRevealActivity() {

    int cx = rootLayout.getWidth() / 2;
    int cy = rootLayout.getHeight() / 2;

    float finalRadius = Math.max(rootLayout.getWidth(), rootLayout.getHeight());

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    Animator circularReveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(rootLayout, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
    circularReveal.setDuration(1000);

    // make the view visible and start the animation
    rootLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    circularReveal.start();
}
```

**Edit 1**

The definition for `R.anim.do_not_move` was added. However, it should work without that line too, if your design does not specify default transitions for activities. Let me know

R.anim.do_not_move:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    />
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborate answer. Is it working for you? I will give it a go this week.

Comment: Working like a charm for me. I just had the feeling that this circular reveal should be possible without merging two activities into one...
If there are problems let me know.

Comment: works great. I changed the cx and cy value to change the point of origin

Comment: What is the definition of R.anim.do_not_move ?

Comment: @JakaDirnbek R.anim.do_not_move is added to override default animations. However, when you have not defined default activity animations, it should work without that line too. I added the code for R.anim.do_not_move to the listing if needed.

Comment: @TheOddAbhi it does not for me. Maybe you're calling `createCircularReveal()` twice or you have some default animation/ overriding animation messing it up for you?
Or maybe a weird phone (e.g. Samsung :D ), which messes up something? Without code I can not help you precisely. You could open a new thread and link it here.

Comment: @StefanMedack I am calling it in globallayoutlistener only. And I have Nexus 5. I think it is because I am doing this in a ViewPager activity where I am adding two fragments to the ViewPager.

Comment: @TheOddAbhi did you find solution for twice revealing ?

Comment: @StefanMedack You shoud add `getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);` in `onGlobalLayout()`. This avoids calling more than once which caused the double revealing. Works here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @WindRider, I added it to the snippets. It actually was already in our sources, to prevent memory leakage, but I forgot to add it here. Hope it also helps TheOddAbhi

Comment: Now it works pretty fine but with some additions to support fullscreen and drawing under the statusbar. Good work!

Comment: @StefanMedack How can you do this to hide an activity?

Comment: @DropArt So far, I haven't needed the other way around, but it should be possible by overwriting `onBackPressed` in your Activity. But if you need some more help. maybe you should ask a new question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @StefanMedack can we launch an app with circular reveal animation.

Comment: @Saeed Masoumi can we launch an app with circular reveal animation.

Comment: @rup35h yes of course, also there are some utility libraries for circular reveal on github you can use them

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi thanks for swift response. What i found is that we can use open activity from another opened activity but not the launch app. Can you please give me some lead. thank you :)

Comment: @rup35h yes, a transparent activity with a circular reveal after `setContentView`.

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi can you please elaborate this.

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi What about the activity with actionbar?

Comment: I want to finish my first activity once reveal is complete. Where should I do that?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the only working solution I found. Even `ActivityOptionsCompat#makeClipRevealAnimation()` does not work correctly. One thing: You should add `overridePendingTransition(0, 0)` after the `finish()` call to prevent a flicker when the activity is finished.

Comment: Instead of creating a `@+id/rootLayout`, couldn't we just use `window.decorView` ?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to reverse the circular reveal on leaving activity, use the following modification to onBackPressed().

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        int cx = rootLayout.getWidth();
        int cy = 0;
        float finalRadius = Math.max(rootLayout.getWidth(), rootLayout.getHeight());
        Animator circularReveal = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(rootLayout, cx, cy, finalRadius, 0);

        circularReveal.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                rootLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });
        circularReveal.setDuration(400);
        circularReveal.start();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you can use `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeClipRevealAnimation` .

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html#makeClipRevealAnimation(android.view.View, int, int, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.html#makeClipRevealAnimation(android.view.View, int, int, int, int))

Comment: Works on APi 23+ only, otherwise defaults to standard animation

Comment: Anyway to use this on back button to come back to previously activity?

Answer (score 8):

To reverse the `CircularReveal` animation swap the `startRadius` and `endRadius` arguments.  Also you will need to setup an `AnimatorListener`and in the `onAnimationEnd()` callback method is where you can call `finishAfterTransition()`.  This is for when you press the `up navigation` or click on the `back button`.

Comment: You should say how to achieve reverse animation in detail.

Answer (score 2):

ou have to draw the circle view, and after that you should create an animation to it.

Creating the circle view:

```
public class Circle extends View {

    private static final int START_ANGLE_POINT = 90;

    private final Paint paint;
    private final RectF rect;

    private float angle;

    public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        final int strokeWidth = 40;

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        //Circle color
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        //size 200x200 example
        rect = new RectF(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, 200 + strokeWidth, 200 + strokeWidth);

        //Initial Angle (optional, it can be zero)
        angle = 120;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, START_ANGLE_POINT, angle, false, paint);
    }

    public float getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }
}
```

Creating the animation class to set the new angle:

```
public class CircleAngleAnimation extends Animation {

    private Circle circle;

    private float oldAngle;
    private float newAngle;

    public CircleAngleAnimation(Circle circle, int newAngle) {
        this.oldAngle = circle.getAngle();
        this.newAngle = newAngle;
        this.circle = circle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation) {
        float angle = oldAngle + ((newAngle - oldAngle) * interpolatedTime);

        circle.setAngle(angle);
        circle.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Put circle into your layout:

```
<com.package.Circle
    android:id="@+id/circle"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

And finally starting the animation:

```
Circle circle = (Circle) findViewById(R.id.circle);

CircleAngleAnimation animation = new CircleAngleAnimation(circle, 240);
animation.setDuration(1000);
circle.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: this is not wat user asked, but anyway this helped me alot