# Implementing Floating action button expanding an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, transition, floating-action-button

> I am currently building my app's ui under material design. A fragment
> in  my app contain a FAB,which starts a new activity on Onclick. Now i
> need to make the transition between FAB click and new activity like
> the expansion of the FAB,revealing the new activity layout.
>
> I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624935/floatingactionbutton-expand-into-a-new-activity) post which also answers the same question,but the
> method seems inefficient as per my requirements as my new activity
> contains spinners,edittexts,buttons etc
>
> I want to implement my FAB to activity transition like below images,

[image: 1st][image: 2nd][image: 3rd]