# How to start new activity from the point where it is clicked

Tags: android, android-animation

When I click any image or text the activity should start from the position of image or text which is clicked. I tried for

```
overridingTransition(R.anim.xyz,R.anim.z);
```

but this is static. I want to start the activity from the image position not from left right or corner of screens

Comment: What you need is a reveal animation . See this library https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal

Comment: for this we have to add libary. Is there any option other then this? @JaswanthManigundan

Comment: This should help you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958834/circular-reveal-transition-for-new-activity

Answer (score 3):

Activity Shared Element Transition

[image: Activity Shared Element Transition]

Source: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition

What you need to do is to provide a transition name that both Activites can use to create a transition animation with.

So the `ImageView` you click in the first activity needs the attribute  `android:transitionName="your_shared_transition_name"` and then you need to set the same attribute for the `ImageView` in the target Activity too.

To use the shared transition name you need to provide the start intent with a option Bundle like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
    makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, (View)yourImageView, "your_shared_transition_name");
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

And to make the Activities support this type of transitions you need to add the attribute `android:windowContentTransitions` to your `Theme`

```
...
 <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
...
```

-follow the linked tutorial above for a more detailed explanation